# Pandas groupby and count across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have data ordered by ID, Year, and then a series of event flags indicating whether a thing did or did not happen for that ID in that year:

| ID | Year | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2017 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2015 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2017 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I'd like to group by ID and Year and apply a cumulative count to each "event" column, such that I'm left with something like the following

| ID | Year | x_total | y_total | z_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2016 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2017 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2015 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2016 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2017 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

I've looked at various options using `cumsum` and `cumcount` but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')[['x', 'y', 'z']].cumsum()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) to get the cumulative count to each "event" column.  Then add `_total` as suffix to the column names by [`.add_suffix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and then join with the first 2 columns:

```
df[['ID', 'Year']].join(df.groupby('ID')[['x', 'y', 'z']].cumsum().add_suffix('_total'))
```

**Result:**

```
   ID  Year  x_total  y_total  z_total
0   1  2015        0        1        0
1   1  2016        1        2        0
2   1  2017        1        3        1
3   2  2015        1        0        1
4   2  2016        2        1        1
5   2  2017        2        2        2
```